# Unordered Iteration of a Container

Tags: c++

My intent is to mask the implementation details of the container such that the client is not permitted to rely on the implicit insertion order. I'm trying to enforce this by somehow altering the order in which iteration occurs.

I have a container which I want to be randomly ordered when iterating. Here is some pseudo code.

```
namespace abc
{
template<class T>
class RandomList
{
  void insert(T t);
  T erase(T t);
  iterator begin();
  iterator end();
}
}

namespace test
{
  int main()
  {
    RandomList<int> list;
    list.insert(1);
    list.insert(2);
    list.insert(3);

    for (typename RandomList::iterator iter = list.begin();
         iter != list.end(); ++iter)
    {
       std::cout << iter << std::endl;
    }
  }    
}
```

Output:

```
3, 1, 2
```

My question is, what is the best way to implement RandomList. My naive thought is to just hold a member std::list and do rand() to determine whether insert does front inserts or back inserts.

Any other ideas?

I'm using mostly C++03, but I have access to boost.

Comment: Don't bother. Just document that users shouldn't rely on order. (They shouldn't anyway unless the API tells you you can!)

Comment: *"My naive thought is to just hold a member std::list and do rand() to determine whether insert does front inserts or back inserts."* - that's entirely reasonable.  Alternatively, if you sometimes have performance reasons for wanting to use a `vector` you could randomly pick an index between 0 and the new size - 1, and if it's `<` new size - 1 then `push_back` a copy of the element at that index before overwriting the index with the inserted value.

Comment: @John3136: it's *rarely* productive to test to such a high standard, but that's far from never - if the system's reliability requirements are indeed that high (the proverbial pace maker, nuclear power plant, space vehicle etc.) then the functionality sought in the question's entirely reasonable.  And sometimes regulatory pressures (e.g. in the banking industry) require some concrete action to lessen the chance of an issue happening again, even if that's pretty paranoid.

Comment: @TonyD Then you'd mock out the collection and test that the client code rather than adding complexity and processing time to your collection.

Comment: @John316: it's likely easy and effective to use `RandomList` during testing and `std::list` for production... if you can't see that we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Creating an interface and using non-performant code (w/ random ordering) in the testing environment is probably the correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand all aspects of your problem. I think what qualifies as a good solution largely depends on the application and what the type `T` is going to be in practice. In any case, I suggest that you alter the interface of `RandomList` (see below).

First, your idea to use `std::list` internally and randomly insert at front or back seems to be a possible solution.

I do not think that it is a good idea to use `std::vector` if you aim for a broad range of applications. The reason is that `std::vector` implementations usually do a lot of extra stuff internally that may harm the performance/memory requirements of your container type. Usually `std::vector` uses a memory buffer that is larger than the actual size of the vector to avoid allocations on subsequent calls of insertion operations like `push_back`. Therefore, the performance of insertions may vary on subsequent calls (suddenly the vector buffer has to be increased again...), and your container may use much more memory than is really necessary. Again: this might not be a problem, it depends on your application and what `T` actually is. But as a user of your `RandomList` interface, I would be bothered to hear that it uses `std::vector` internally...

So if you are just asking for "another idea" and also want to allow for multiple insertions of the same value into the container - here is one: in essence, make `RandomList` into a `std::map` wrapper. The randomization should be implemented by properly employing the map key. To iterate the container you simply use the iterator of `std::map`. This actually gives you references to (key,value) pairs. You could use the `std::map` key to implement additional features that might be interesting. First of all, you can hide the key type - and therefore hide details of your implementation - by introducing a typedef `RandomList::handle`. I recommend that the method `insert` actually returns a `RandomList::handle`. In this way, you allow users to directly access specific container values by adding a method `access` to your interface. `access` takes `RandomList::handle` as argument and returns a reference to the corresponding map value. If you alter the interface in this way, it is consistent that your `RandomList` iterator (which is just the map iterator) refers to pairs of `RandomList::handle` and `T`. Whether this is useful or not largely depends on what `T` is going to be.

`erase` should take `RandomList::handle` as argument. Again: if multiple insertions are not welcome, the idea to base your implementation on `std::map` is problematic, or at least should be approached in a different manner.

This approach allows for a neat control of the "randomization implementation". For example, if you use `std::list` with random insertions at front or back, the implementation of the randomization is very closely tied to your internal storage/container implementation. An implementation on the basis of `std::map` could keep the details of the randomization more seperate from the rest of the implementation, as the randomization is fully controlled in terms of the map key selection. For example, if you use an `int` as key, you could hold a counter internally which is incremented on subsequent insertions. The current value of the counter is used as key for the next map insertion. As this would lead to a completely unbalanced tree structure, `RandomList` would behave like an ordinary `std::list` on iterations. I would suggest to choose new key values in such a manner that the tree is perfectly balanced. In this way, the direct access feature is implemented most efficiently (cause search operations are fast), and a straightforward iteration of the `RandomList`/`std::map` via `begin()`/`end()` should lead to a sufficiently "random" result.

Finally, regarding the interface: I suggest that you use perfect forwarding for the `insert` operation instead of a direct copy. In this way, you avoid unneccessary copy operations when inserting elements into `std::map` (same story for `std::list` of course), and you additionally allow for move operations. If you do not want to use perfect forwarding, at least change `T` to `const T&`, as another copy operation is required to insert the object into the `std::list`/`std::map` container.

Comment: Interesting write-up.  I'm making yours the "answer".  My initial case was for "T" to literally be anything. The more general sort of context is that this was for event binding. I want to ensure that the events are not ordered systematically to prevent clients from relying on some implicit ordering scheme; randomness seemed the best way to preserve that. I've debated about using the map with the "key" or an "address" internally.  I actually ended up punting on the problem so I can't provide any additional insight.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your use case but it is an interesting question nonetheless.

Tony D's suggestion to use a `std::vector` seemed like a good one. I've put the inserted value at the end and then swapped with a random element:

```
template<typename T>
class RandomList {
  std::vector<T> list;
  RandomIndex    randomIndex;
public:
  using iterator = typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator;
  iterator begin() { return list.begin(); }
  iterator end() { return list.end(); }

  void insert(const T& t) {
    list.push_back(t);

    auto i = randomIndex(list.size());

    using std::swap;
    swap(list[i], list.back());
  }
};
```

Where `RandomIndex` is a (non-templated) helper functor to get a random index:

```
class RandomIndex {
  std::mt19937 eng;
public:
  RandomIndex() : eng(std::random_device{}()) {}

  size_t operator()(size_t size) {
    auto dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t>{0, size - 1};
    return dist(eng);    
  }
};
```

I'm not sure about the quality of the randomness but it should be enough to ensure a client can't make any assumptions about the order of the elements.

Comment: The C++11 random number generation is interesting, and not something I knew about. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid random insertions, and randomize iteration.  The idea that a large container is correct, will be difficult to see visually, and understanding insertion issues difficult